# VBA Copying specific data related to names from one workbook to another and pasting it into another Workbook to the correct corresponding name

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with some excel data. I have two workbooks. One contains a pivot table with some people's names and some data points, such as Jeff 10. I want to copy the 10 and paste it into another workbook which would have Jeff and a blank in the next cell over. Another complicated step is that it could be Jeff 10, but the 10 corresponds to a specific team. No matter what team it corresponds to the value still is in the cell next to the name on the source sheet as it is part of a pivot table. I can get the code to copy values for me, but it does not paste them in the correct name slot, or team slot on the other workbook. Below is what I currently have. Any help is appreciated.

```
Function WorksheetExists(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Boolean
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   On Error Resume Next
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
   On Error GoTo 0
   WorksheetExists = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function

Function GetWorksheet(wb As Workbook, sheetName As String) As Worksheet
   If WorksheetExists(wb, sheetName) Then
      Set GetWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
   Else
      MsgBox "Worksheet'" & sheetName & "' not found", vbCritical
      Set GetWorksheet = Nothing
   End If
End Function

Sub Aged_Account_Pivot_Tables()
   Dim sourceFile As Workbook
   Dim targetFile As Workbook
   Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
   Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
   Dim pivotSheet1 As Worksheet
   Dim sourceRange As Range
   Dim targetRange As Range
   Dim sourceFilePath As Variant
   Dim targetFilePath As Variant
   Dim pt1 As PivotTable
   Dim pt1FieldColumn As PivotField
   Dim pt1FieldColumn2 As PivotField
   Dim fullName As String
   Dim matchedCell As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim copySpot As Range
   Dim pasteRange As Range
   Dim copySheet As Worksheet
   Dim pTable As PivotTable
   Dim newRange As Range
   ' Select Source File
   MsgBox "Please choose the source file (the discretionary requests log)"
   sourceFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", title:="Select Source Workbook")
   
   If sourceFilePath = False Then
      Exit Sub ' User canceled file selection
   End If
   ' Set workbooks and sheets
   Set sourceFile = Workbooks.Open(sourceFilePath)
   Set sourceSheet = sourceFile.Sheets("Discretionary Requests")
   ' Create tables
   Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:S1500")
   Set pivotSheet1 = sourceFile.Sheets.Add(After:=sourceSheet)
   pivotSheet1.Name = "Pivot Discretionary Requests"
   Set pt1 = pivotSheet1.PivotTableWizard(xlDatabase, sourceRange, TableName:="Test")
   
   With pt1
      Set pt1FieldColumn = pt1.PivotFields("CST of TO Approver")
      pt1FieldColumn.Orientation = xlRowField
      Set pt1FieldColumn2 = pt1.PivotFields("Completed by Trust Specialist")
      pt1FieldColumn2.Orientation = xlRowField
      Set pt1Field = pt1.PivotFields("Completed by Trust Specialist")
      pt1Field.Orientation = xlDataField
      pt1Field.Function = xlCount
   End With
   
   pivotSheet1.Columns.AutoFit
   pt1.ClearAllFilters
   pt1.RefreshTable
   ' Select Target File
   MsgBox "Please choose the target file (2023 Dashboard)"
   targetFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", title:="Select Source    Workbook")
   
   If targetFilePath = False Then
      Exit Sub ' User canceled file selection
   End If
   
   ' Set workbooks and sheets
   Set targetFile = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)
   Set targetSheet = targetFile.Sheets("Working Month data")
   Range("C3:G21").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   Range("C46:F65").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   sourceFile.Activate
   Set copySheet = sourceFile.Sheets("Pivot Discretionary Requests")
   Set pTable = copySheet.PivotTables("Test")
   pTable.TableRange1.Copy
   Set newRange = copySheet.Range("F1")
   newRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Set copySpot = copySheet.Range("F1:H50")
   Set pasteRange = targetSheet.Range("A46:F65")
   
   For Each cell In copySpot
      fullName = cell.value
      Set matchedCell = pasteRange.Find(What:=fullName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then
         cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy destination:=matchedCell.Offset(0, 1)
      Else
         MsgBox ("Name Not Found")
      End If
   Next cell
   
   MsgBox "Macro has finished running"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please learn how and when to indent your code - this massive block of code is so damn hard to read.